# Vertical tables with JBehave

Tags: jbehave

By default JBehave presents outcome and parameterized tables in a tabular way, eg.

```
header1|header2|header3  
value1 |value2 |value3
```

is there a way to present this data vertically instead ?

```
header1|value1  
header2|value2  
header3|value3
```

I'm aware of the *Jbehave-html-output.ftl* file and its `renderTable` macro, but before I start digging into this - I'd like to make sure there's no easier way to achieve the above.